# How to shift all lines to the right in Ruby text file?

Tags: ruby

Consider, I have a file with the following text:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "age"
  t.string  "first_name"
  t.string  "last_name"
end
```

What would be a neat way to shift it to the right as if there was **"\t"** symbol before each line?

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "age"
    t.string  "first_name"
    t.string  "last_name"
  end
```

My question has nothing to do with text editor. I'm asking how to shift text in file programmatically.

Comment: Depends on your editor :-)

Comment: Why do you want to / have to do that programmatically?

Comment: @Stefan I'm writing my gem related to migrations. After I parse some data, my migrations are created like [this](http://storage3.static.itmages.com/i/16/0531/h_1464699740_4499144_d16fd2ff00.png).

Comment: does it need to be in ruby?

Comment: Does your gem create those files?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to correctly indent the lines when writing the files instead of post-processing them a second time?

Comment: @Stefan The thing is that I extract those chunks of code using regexp and then insert the whole create_table block to each file.

Comment: @BillyLogan it's time to show some code :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by processing the file line-by-line and writing to a new file.  Try something like this:

```
spaces = 8
original_filename = 'outdented.txt'
new_filename = 'indented.txt'

File.open(new_filename, 'w') do |out_file|
  File.foreach(original_filename) do |line|
     out_file.puts "#{" "*spaces}#{line}"
  end
end
```

When run on this file (`outdented.txt`):

```
This file is not indented
Each line rests against the left margin
  Except this line
And that's all this file does
```

produces this output (`indented.txt`):

```
        This file is not indented
        Each line rests against the left margin
          Except this line
        And that's all this file does
```

If you like, you can remove the original file and rename the new file to the original filename:

```
File.delete(original_filename)
File.rename(new_filename, original_filename)
```

If you prefer tabs, you can choose replace the `spaces` variable with a `tabs` variable, and change the character to output:

```
tabs = 2
original_filename = 'outdented.txt'
new_filename = 'indented.txt'

File.open(new_filename, 'w') do |out_file|
  File.foreach(original_filename) do |line|
     out_file.puts "#{"\t"*tabs}#{line}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

First let's construct a file to be read.

```
str =<<_
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "age"
  t.string  "first_name"
  t.string  "last_name"
end
_

FNameIn  = "temp_in"
FNameOut = "temp_out"

File.write(FNameIn,str)
  #=> 116
```

116 characters written to file.

If your file is not huge (small enough to "gulp" it), this will do:

```
insert = ' '{4}
File.write(FNameOut, File.read(FNameIn).gsub(/^/,"#{insert}"))
  #=> 136
```

`/^/` matches the beginning of each line.

To confirm:

```
puts File.read(FNameOut)
    create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.integer "age"
      t.string  "first_name"
      t.string  "last_name"
    end
```

To replace the file:

```
FNameOut = FNameIn
```

Comment: Your variable naming is not ruby-like. Don't use CamelCase in ruby, use snake_case.

Comment: @pascalbetz, `FNameIn` and `FNameOut` are constants. :-)

Comment: Yes, I know. Unless it is a class name, use snake_case.
https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#screaming-snake-case

Comment: ...but you said, "...variable naming is not ruby-like." Ah, the style guide wants me to use "screaming snake case". It is just a guide, of course. I elect to not follow that advice. I consider screaming-anything in Ruby to be discordant, upsetting to my sensibilities.

Comment: Yes, it's just a guide and you can name your variables and constants as you like. Following common practices and guidelines makes code easier to read IMHO. 
And yes I wrote "variable" instead of "constants". My bad. Given that there are no "enforced" constants in ruby... i'd say they are variables as well. Anyway: i actually like your "gulp" method with Regexp, did not think about this approach.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the text editor you are using.

E.g. [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) allows you to do it in several ways (select columns using the right-click ..)

**After your edit**

It's not a good practice to use tab `\t` for indentation.
The best way would be to replace all tabs `"\t"` with double space `"  "`. This should be enough